# How to add model of object from non default localisation?

Tags: gazebo

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Hi,

could you tell me:

- is there any option to add model of object from non default localisation?
  like: add different path to this GUI?
  http://snag.gy/Du37O.jpg
- I am using ROS and Gazebo and I am a little bit confused, what is the extension of models (objects which can be added to the world)?
  .sdf, .world, .model, .dae?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/7463/how-to-add-model-of-object-from-non-default-localisation?/) by [green96](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/1016/green96/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 13 on 2014-11-17

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

The paths displayed in the Insert Model Tab correlate to the `GAZEBO_MODEL_PATH` environment variable.

SDF & URDF serve roughly the same purpose. Both are formats that describe robots (models). SDF has additional capabilities, such as supporting lights, terrain, sensors, etc. The extensions '.model' and '.world' are hold-overs from early versions of Gazebo. A '.model' file is an SDF file that contains one model, while a '.world' file is an SDF file that contains the description of an entire environment.

DAE files are used to describe 3D meshes and their textures.

---

Originally posted by [nkoenig](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/5/nkoenig/) with karma: 7676 on 2014-11-17

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [green96](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/1016/green96/) on 2014-11-17**:
Thank you for your answer. I add path to the .bashrc file, and this path appear in insert tag, but I can't choose anything. This folder which is linked to this variable consist *.model files. Do you have any idea what is wrong?
http://snag.gy/HNwe5.jpg

please check it: http://pastebin.com/mebhNW1R
I am not sure but is this normal that when I call echo it gives ' : ' sign before path?

**Comment by [green96](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/1016/green96/) on 2014-11-17**:
Is it a bug? when I call echo I get " :  " before or after path...
http://pastebin.com/HtVNj7M7

**Comment by [nkoenig](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/5/nkoenig/) on 2014-11-18**:
Gazebo expects models to be contained in directories. One directory per model. Each directory should have a `model.config` file along with your SDF file(s), textures, meshes, etc. Take a look in `~/.gazebo/models` for examples.

**Comment by [green96](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/1016/green96/) on 2014-11-18**:
I know, I had checked it before but I have only *.models and *.dae files. I would like to add tag / mark to gazebo. I know that it was possible and it was working when ROS fuerte was released.
Like here: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wG1OHN7ik3w
Some time ago, there was different standard to add models to world?

**Comment by [nkoenig](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/5/nkoenig/) on 2014-11-18**:
The `model.config` file is used to tell Gazebo about a model. Make sure that you have a `model.config` in your model directory. Also make sure that the `model.config` refers to the correct SDF file, which should exist in the same directory as the `model.config` file.

**Comment by [green96](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/1016/green96/) on 2014-11-18**:
Unfortunately I don't have any sdf file and model.config file. Should I create them?
I spend some time and I found in google that few years ago people ad files like here: http://answers.ros.org/question/43809/unable-to-include-model-files-for-objects-in-world-file-for-simulation-in-ubuntu-1204-fuerte/
or like here: http://answers.ros.org/question/42529/how-to-import-collada-dae-files-into-gazebo-rosfuerte/
so what is the best solution? creation .sdf files or using URDF?

**Comment by [green96](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/1016/green96/) on 2014-11-18**:
I am asking because posts which I linked are a little bit old. What should I do?

**Comment by [nkoenig](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/5/nkoenig/) on 2014-11-18**:
Can you take a look at this [tutorial](http://gazebosim.org/tutorials?tut=model_structure&cat=build_robot)? It might help you.

**Comment by [green96](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/1016/green96/) on 2014-11-20**:
Thank you for your support!

**Comment by [nkoenig](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/5/nkoenig/) on 2014-11-20**:
Sure thing.